# Where is python path being loaded from

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, easy-install, qgis

I am having problems debugging the KyngChaos QGIS installation. I have my python set up using Anaconda, but KyngChaos ignores this and instead looks for the `/Library/Frameworks` version. This and other `pth` files scattered around (`~/.qgis2` for example) means that the python path returned in QGIS is a mess of folders, including some System folders, as well as doubles etc. Somewhere along the line the path for Matplotlib is superseded, despite having installed both the Anaconda package and KyngChaos own 'framework'.

Is there any way of finding out where an individual path is appended to the whole? I am trying to track down how all the paths referenced but it's proving quite tricky and time consuming.

#### Comments:

So, because I installed Anaconda before QGIS, pyparsing has to be installed by first commenting out in `.bash_profile` the path to the Anaconda Python and use the standard python.

```
Wed Nov 27 13:43:31 | $ sudo easy_install pyparsing
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
Wed Nov 27 13:43:57 | $ ls /usr/bin/easy*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 925 Jan 30 2013 /usr/bin/easy_install*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 421 Jan 30 2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.5*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 454 Jan 30 2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 454 Jan 30 2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7*
```

Got `pyparsing` installed from sourceforge instead. Not solved the `easy_install` mystery. QGIS runs, Anaconda installation runs.

Comment: So, because I installed Anaconda before QGIS, pyparsing has to be installed by first commenting out in .bash_profile the path to the Anaconda Python and use the standard python.

Comment: Wed Nov 27 13:43:31 | $ sudo easy_install pyparsing
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
Wed Nov 27 13:43:57 | $ ls /usr/bin/easy*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  925 Jan 30  2013 /usr/bin/easy_install*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  421 Jan 30  2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.5*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  454 Jan 30  2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  454 Jan 30  2013 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7*

Comment: Got pyparsing installed from sourceforge instead. Not solved the easy_install mystery. QGIS runs, Anaconda installation runs.

Comment: With QGIS 2.0 you can easily override system variables like `PYTHONPATH`. If you go to 'settings -> options -> system' you can points QGIS to a specific Python installation.

Comment: Will try that soon, thanks. For now I really need to work.